# How can I customize the TabBar width to fill the Screen width?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-test

[image]

I  like to do somthing like this,the width of the tabs should be 1/3 the with of the screnn,I try to rwap the Containers in Expended widget but it not work , I have try and this is my code:

```
Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xff433579)),
      child: new TabBar(
        indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
        controller: _controller,
        onTap: (index){
          setState(() {
            print(index);
            cureentIndex = index ;
          });
        },
        tabs: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: cureentIndex ==0 ? Color(0xff231751): Color(0xff433579),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: cureentIndex == 0 ? Radius.circular(0.0) : Radius.circular(20.0),
                topRight: cureentIndex == 0 ? Radius.circular(20.0) : Radius.circular(0.0),
                bottomLeft: cureentIndex == 0 ? Radius.circular(0.0) : Radius.circular(20.0),
                bottomRight: cureentIndex == 1 ? Radius.circular(20.0) : Radius.circular(20.0),
              )
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/sp_medatation.svg'),
                Text('Séances\nSophro',style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white
                ),textAlign: TextAlign.center,)
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: cureentIndex ==1 ? Color(0xff231751): Color(0xff433579),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: cureentIndex == 1 ? Radius.circular(20.0) : Radius.circular(20.0),
                  topRight: cureentIndex == 1 ? Radius.circular(20.0) : Radius.circular(20.0),
                  bottomLeft: cureentIndex == 0 ? Radius.circular(20.0) : Radius.circular(0.0),
                  bottomRight: cureentIndex == 2 ? Radius.circular(20.0) : Radius.circular(0.0),
                )
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/sp_book.svg'),
                Text('Histoires\net blagues',style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),)
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: cureentIndex ==2 ? Color(0xff231751): Color(0xff433579),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: cureentIndex == 2 ? Radius.circular(20.0) : Radius.circular(0.0),
                  topRight: cureentIndex == 2 ? Radius.circular(0.0) : Radius.circular(0.0),
                  bottomLeft: cureentIndex == 1 ? Radius.circular(20.0) : Radius.circular(0.0),
                  bottomRight: cureentIndex == 2 ? Radius.circular(0.0) : Radius.circular(0.0),
                )
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/sp_music.svg'),
                Text('Music',style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

I got this, this tabs do not fill the width of the screen, how to custum the TabBar iteam to fill the width of the screen :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
tabs: [
  Container(width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3,child:YourWidget()),
  Container(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3,child:YourWidget()),
  Container(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3,child:YourWidget()),
 ]
```

or try this it worked for me

```
body: Container(
                height: mediaQuerySize.height,
                child: DefaultTabController(
                  length: 3,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      TabBar(
                        tabs: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0),
                            child: Tab(
                              text: 'details',
                              icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                                'assets/icons/details.svg',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0),
                            child: Tab(
                              text: 'operation',
                              icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                                'assets/icons/operation.svg',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0),
                            child: Tab(
                              text: 'disease',
                              icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                                'assets/icons/plant_disease.svg',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: TabBarView(
                          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          children: [
                            PlantInfo(
                              plantModel: plantModel,
                            ),
                            PlantDetailOperation(
                              plantId: widget.plantId,
                            ),
                            PlantDetailDiseases(
                              plantId: widget.plantId,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: @AdilSakout try the next one I've edited the answer

Comment: thank you Moaid for your help, it not work, I made it from scratch